# passkey authentication on android platform

Tags: android, passkey

I have one quick point to confirm.

On Android platform with google-password-manager,  on any device is it correct that
there can NOT be more than one passkey of same account (eg., chirag@walmart.com ) per Relying-party (walmart.com)  EVEN **if the attached google-account is different.**

And secondly,  if I am using 3rd party password manager like Dashlane or Bitwarden,  I would like to know who exactly creates the key-pair.
**Is it part of Dashlane code**  OR  **is it created by platform-authenticator and handed it to Dashlane  ?**

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember that depends on the Android version. On Android 14 you can have third party apps as passkey providers, before to my knowledge only the Android integrated platform authenticator can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Typically authenticators only allow one passkey per user handle (i.e. user.id). RPs should use the same user handle for each unique account.

Each account for each passkey provider is logically a unique authenticator. So if I had 2 Google accounts on my device, both with GPM enabled as passkey providers, and I also had a 3rd passkey provider enabled, say Bitwarden, I could end up with 3 passkeys for an account at the RP.

If a user has multiple passkey providers on their device, they are given the choice of where to save it.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent Tim !!  You answer is totally logical as that is how it should be.
**So much so that I am going to call following a bug in google.**

As I write (02/02)  ,   I tried to create a second passkey for the same account (test@hotmail.com)   while **explicitly selecting a different google account** on my latest Samsung S23  device.
It failed.

In order to make sure the RP has NO ROLE to play in it,  I tried to do the same on   webauthn.io   (test@hotmail.com)  and it failed too.

In order to make sure that  device-vendor has NO ROLE to play, I tried same exercise on Pixel 6a (android 14)   and it failed too.